# USB hard drive loses permissions after 30 seconds

Tags: permissions

The hard drive has two ext2 partitions. One is encrypted. After connecting the drive to the laptop I can write to that encrypted partition. But after a short minute all write actions are disabled. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` will show system logs that cover the event. Read `man journalctl`. Each log message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in `[]` of the issuer and a colon (`:`). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read `man logger`.

Comment: Check S.M.A.R.T. info for this disk to eliminate the case of the drive failing.

Comment: Thanks. Not one line in the terminal makes sense to me. Now I get "An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: The requested operation has failed: Error unlocking /dev/sdd1: Failed to activate device: File exists" in Dolphin when I plug in the hard drive. What is that about?

Comment: Maybe this drive cannot be encrypted? It is a Samsung One Touch 2 TB.